# any way to schedule an R program to run daily?

Tags: r, compilation, executable

I am using R program to collect and update data from some local and online sources, which are updated frequently.

Since these sources are fixed, there is no argument to pass to the program, and everything is routine.

Now my supervisor wants me to set this as a scheduled daily task. I know it is impossible for .r file. Is there any way to compile the r file to executable file? such as .exe, .bat, ... ...

I don't need the executable file to be standalone, I can keep R in my computer.

any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why it is impossible for an .R file - you can call R from the command line with a command that looks like `R CMD BATCH myFun.R`. If you can schedule that daily, you're good to go.

Comment: I am sorry. I THOUGH it is impossible. Good to know the trick. Let me think about it, never knew it before.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the standard OS facilities (`cron`/`at` on Unix) to run `R` with the appropriate argument.

E.g., if you add the functions you need to `.Rprofile`, you can do

```
R --no-save --no-restore -q -e 'MyFunc(my,args)'
```

Alternatively, you might want to use [Batch Execution of R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html).

Answer (score 2):

For Windows I have hundreds of scripts that are set up with bat files similar to the below. It assumes that you have a `NameOfScript.bat` and a `NameOfScript.r` in the same folder and then run the .bat file from Scheduler and it logs everything from stdout/err to `NameOfScript_yyyy-mm-dd.log` in the same folder. I normally have the log folder seperate but adding that can be done just by changing the definition of `LOG_FILE`. Also passes in the folder it's in to R just in case you need to output some files in the folder.

```
IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) (
    SET R_SCRIPT="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\R\\R-2.15.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe"
) ELSE (
    SET R_SCRIPT="%ProgramFiles%\\R\\R-2.15.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe"
)
IF NOT EXIST %R_SCRIPT% GOTO FAIL
SET SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
SET SCRIPT_DIR=%SCRIPT_DIR:\=\\%
SET BATCH_FILE=%0
SET BATCH_FILE=%BATCH_FILE:"=%
SET SCRIPT_TO_RUN="%BATCH_FILE:.bat=.r%"
SET day=%DATE:~0,2%
SET month=%DATE:~3,2%
SET year=%DATE:~6,4%
SET yyyymmdd=%year%-%month%-%day%
SET LOG_FILE="%BATCH_FILE:.bat=%"_%yyyymmdd%.log
SET SCRIPT_DIR="%SCRIPT_DIR%"

%R_SCRIPT% --internet2 --max-mem-size=2047M --no-restore --no-save --args %SCRIPT_DIR% < %SCRIPT_TO_RUN% >> %LOG_FILE% 2>&1

PAUSE

EXIT /B 0 
:FAIL
ECHO RScript not found. Failed process
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also call the R script from C#, and run the C# project as a scheduled task.